Framework 'Reachability' Not Found Error When Running Flutter Project on iOS Device (Xcode 16.2, Flutter SDK 3.24.3)
I'm getting framework error in Xcode while I'll try to run my Flutter project in iOS device
Error (Xcode): Framework 'Reachability' not found

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 16 Pro.

System Configuration:
Flutter SDK: 3.24.3
Xcode: 16.2
Device: iPhone 16 Pro (simulator)
MacBook: M3 Chip (Apple Silicon)
What I've tried:
Cleaned and rebuild: I ran flutter clean and flutter pub get, then rebuilt the project, but the error persists. Pod Install: I also navigated to the iOS/ folder and ran pod install, but it didn’t resolve the issue.

You could try  "pod deintegrate" then "pod install"

@duckSern1108 Thank you for giving answers, but i have already implemented that, is't working.

@ZeelkumarSojitra Are you still stuck on it? I've had the same error for days

@EdgarSaenz Yes still i'm facing this error.

For me it worked!
Xcode-->Runner-->Build Setting-->Search(OTHER_LDFLAGS)-->Other Linker Flags Clear all

After remove the lines
"-framework",
"\"Reachability\""

of OTHER_LDFLAGS on ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj, now i'm able to run my project without problems.
if it doesnt work maybe you must also remove theReachabilitySwift line on HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS at the same file.
In my case, i use connectivity_plus package and it seems like it removed its dependency over reachability so its doesnt needed it anymore. Make sure you do that for all your schemas

Thank you for the answer, but while i'm removing <"-framework", ""Reachability"">  this lines so i'can able to run project in IOS device.

You can also try complete removing OTHER_LDFLAGS and HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS variables from your project.pbxproj and retry, i dont know if this can have other implications but at least it runs
